# xPlayer is null just after a player login

Tags: server, lua, fivem

I have a FiveM script on the server side. The script fails to set `xPlayer` when I connect, when I reload the script once connected to the server everything works as expected.

```
RegisterServerEvent("eventScript:Ping", function()
     local _source = source
      Citizen.Wait(3000)
     print('Source: '.._source)
     local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_source)
      print('xPlayer : '..ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_source))  
    if not gameInfo.PlayerTeams[_source] then
        gameInfo.PlayerTeams[_source] = {
            ["Team"] = xPlayer.job.name == 'army' and team2 or team1,
            ["Position"] = GetEntityCoords(GetPlayerPed(_source)),
            ["IsConnected"] = true
        } 
    end
end)
```

Comment: any reason why you don't put any operations on xPlayer into a conditional statement if ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_source) may return nil?

Comment: because _source is not supposed to be null since the request comes from the client
And if my xPlayer is not defined, my script can't run

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect the player hasn't properly loaded or hasn't been assigned all the identifiers, you need to wait until the [`playerJoining`](https://docs.fivem.net/docs/scripting-reference/events/server-events/#playerjoining) event is triggered to access that client's properties on the server. This is not specific to ESX.